# write a batch script for managing password required on login

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to write a batch script that toggles between requiring password on login and NOT requiring password on login for my personal laptop computer.

When I'm at home I want to be able to access the machine if it goes to standby, etc. WITHOUT the password.

Before I leave for school or work I want to be able to run a batch script that re-enables "require password on login"

Does anybody know what kind of command I would need for that?

Answer (score 2):

To configure your system to not prompt when it wakes from sleep/standby you can use these PowerShell functions. If you are new to PowerShell and don't know what to do with them let me know in the comments...

For XP:

```
function Enable-PasswordProtectedWakeup {
    & POWERCFG /GLOBALPOWERFLAG on /OPTION RESUMEPASSWORD
}

function Disable-PasswordProtectedWakeup {
    & POWERCFG /GLOBALPOWERFLAG off /OPTION RESUMEPASSWORD
}
```

For Windows 7:

```
function Set-PasswordProtectedWakeup {
    param ([switch] $Enabled)
    & powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK ([int]$Enabled.ToBool()) # AC Power
    & powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK ([int]$Enabled.ToBool()) # DC Power
    & powercfg -setactive SCHEME_CURRENT
}

# Enable Password On Wake.
Set-PasswordProtectedWakeup -Enabled:$True

# Disable Password On Wake.
Set-PasswordProtectedWakeup -Enabled:$False
```

If you want to configure your machine to not prompt for a password when it boots up and have it auto log you in you can use this PowerShell function to enable auto logon *securely*. This calls the same Win32 API to store your credentials as the auto logon utility from Sysinternals :

http://andyarismendi.blogspot.com/2011/10/powershell-set-secureautologon.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out AutoLogon from Sysinternals.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905